# Dell Windows 7 OA Key- Use on another PC

Tags: window, licensing

If I have a Windows 7 COA Sticker on my PC... (it isnt specifically labeled Dell COA) Is it possible that I could use that same key on a totally different PC? My dell computer is outdated.  I wanted to install that license on a custom PC I've built.  Will that work? I know I would have to possibly call in to activate it.  Any useful info would help.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

**But**:

1. Possible does **not** mean that it is legal to do so.
2. Should you have a non OEM version of windows on the old Dell (e.g. because it came with XP and you bought a full retail version of windows in a shop and installed that on the Dell) then you will need to wipe the old win7 from the Dell.
   1 License -> 1 computer.

Comment: Nah..the old Dell has Vista installed on it..its not using the Win & COA.  I would also wipe the old Dell once i get Windows installed on the NEW pc.

Comment: @Wayne-Z - If the Windows 7 license is not an OEM license then you can install it on another system.